# How to logout from android application.?

Tags: java, android, session

here is my code.but if this runs my app closed from 60seconds.but when i again press  app icon.its open as logged.how to close app with logout.?i added these in my service class.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
private int interval3 = 10; // 10 seconds

private Handler mTimer3 = new Handler();
private Runnable mTask3 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mTimer3.postDelayed(this, interval3 * 1000L);
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10*1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               Log.w("Seconds remaining: ", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
         };
         timer.start();         
    }
};  

public void onCreate() {
    mTimer1.postDelayed(mTask1, interval1 * 1000L); // start the timer for the first time
    mTimer2.postDelayed(mTask2, interval2 * 1000L); // start the timer for the first time
    mTimer3.postDelayed(mTask3, interval3 * 1000L); // start the timer for the first time
}
```

please give me a suggestion.because we need to sign out from app when idle at more time.
thanks all

Comment: Where do you store the sign in credentials?

Comment: you may need to override onPause or onResume methods in your activity and log out in one of them

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas, i not yet got your point dear friend

Comment: @Atha Nor, please can u mention the sample code

Comment: @PriyanRockZ I mean that when you click on app icon and app shows signed it then you might be storing credentials somewhere.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas, this runs in service class.then credentials in sqlite db.how to manage those

Comment: can you post your credentals?

Comment: You can remove/clear your database once your app is closed after 60 seconds.

Comment: alternatively you can also maintain logged in status in shared preferences. check preferences in onresume and clear preferences when needed to logout

Comment: @PriyanRockZ Try this : context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

Comment: @SiddharthVyas. thansk dear friend.i got ur point

Comment: @Droider,thanks dear friend.now i googling preference tutorials :-)

Answer (score 0):

now its ok.i tried with activity class instead of service class and i added code to after login screen going page.now its working perrfect for me :-)

```
public class #MyActivityClass extends Activity {


    //=============================================================================================================================
    private Handler mTimer3 = new Handler();
    private Runnable mTask3 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(10*1000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                   Log.w("Seconds remaining: ", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                                    //Here finally added  finish(); and System.exit(0); methods 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//***Change Here***
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
             };
             timer.start();
             mTimer3.postDelayed(this, interval3 * 1000L);
        }
    };  

    private int interval3 = 10*60; // 60 seconds

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mTimer3 != null) {
            mTimer3.removeCallbacks(mTask3); // cancel the timer
        }
    }
```